# Netbeans no suitable database found

Tags: java, netbeans

it seems i am unable to connect to the database and i am unsure so to why. The database connection properties (id,password,url) is correct i checked however i am not sure on how to resolve the problem. I get the following error .

```
    Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database Configure
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.Configure(Database.java:50)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:61)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database InsertSimulation
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.InsertSimulation(Database.java:219)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:62)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadCurrentSimulation
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadCurrentSimulation(Database.java:341)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:63)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadCurrentConfiguration
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadCurrentConfiguration(Database.java:253)
    at Core.Configuration.ReadCurrentConfiguration(Configuration.java:237)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:64)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadCurrentConfigAsString
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadCurrentConfigAsString(Database.java:386)
    at Core.Configuration.ReadConfigFromDB(Configuration.java:172)
    at Core.Configuration.CompareConfig(Configuration.java:203)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:66)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database InsertConfiguration
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.InsertConfiguration(Database.java:120)
    at Core.Configuration.InsertConfig(Configuration.java:225)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:68)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadCurrentConfiguration
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadCurrentConfiguration(Database.java:253)
    at Core.Configuration.ReadCurrentConfiguration(Configuration.java:237)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:69)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadEssentialAppliances
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadEssentialAppliances(Database.java:483)
    at Core.Configuration.ReadEssentialAppliances(Configuration.java:115)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:71)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadNonEssentialAppliances
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadNonEssentialAppliances(Database.java:431)
    at Core.Configuration.ReadNonEssentialAppliances(Configuration.java:144)
    at Core.Configuration.Configure(Configuration.java:72)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:51)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database InsertHome
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.InsertHome(Database.java:90)
    at Core.SmartHome.InsertSmartHome(SmartHome.java:34)
    at Core.SmartHome.<init>(SmartHome.java:28)
    at Core.Processor.CreateHomes(Processor.java:65)
    at Core.Processor.Start(Processor.java:43)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:52)
Mar 6, 2012 4:22:56 PM Database.Database ReadCurrentHome
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at Database.Database.ReadCurrentHome(Database.java:297)
    at Core.SmartHome.InsertSmartHome(SmartHome.java:35)
    at Core.SmartHome.<init>(SmartHome.java:28)
    at Core.Processor.CreateHomes(Processor.java:65)
    at Core.Processor.Start(Processor.java:43)
    at desktopapplication2.DesktopApplication2.main(DesktopApplication2.java:52)
```

Comment: Its not about the Properties..Its about the "jar" file..Either it is not in the ClassPath..OR it is entirely missing..!!

Comment: ive added the file to the lib but i still get the error

Comment: do you have any other lib in that folder that you are using..??..i am sure its about "lib not present in the classpath"..!!

Comment: Having jar in classpath resolves compile time error, you need to have same jar in lib folder of your application, in other words, same jar should be available at runtime also.

Comment: where do i need to stick the jar file into netbeans? i have mac os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load the driver class manually by calling Class.forName() prior to the statement of getting the database connection. For example, if you are using MySQL database, add the following statement above your statement for getting the database connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Database driver(JAR(s)) to your classpath by using the following steps. This should resolve your issue.

```
1. Select your project from the Projects explorer.
2. Right click -> Properties.
3. Select Libraries from Categories list.
4. Click on Add JAR/Folder button.
5. Add your jar(s) & click on OK to finish the process.
```